# Controlling LED on MagSafe 2 (sending arbitrary data to sense pin)

Tags: macos, low-level, led

I would like to programmatically change LED on MagSafe 2. There is a circuit board that handles sense pin signals and the signals are actually known. The problem is actually sending those signals through OS X.

The only document about MagSafe hacking I was able to find was this blog post by Ken Shirriff
http://www.righto.com/2013/06/teardown-and-exploration-of-magsafe.html. The interesting

The signals Ken found are as follows (just for the sake of completeness):

```
void writeDS2413(int n) {
  uint8_t buf[3];
  net.reset();
  net.skip();
  buf[0] = 0x5a; // PIO access write
  buf[1] = 0xfc | (n&3); // data in lower two bits
  buf[2] = ~buf[1]; // inverted
  net.write_bytes(buf, 3, true /* power on */);
}

// ...
writeDS2413(3); // off
writeDS2413(1); // orange
writeDS2413(2); //green
writeDS2413(0); //yellow
```

Is there a OS X layer that allows low level communication with MagSafe? I assume it registers as some kind of device when plugged in - that could be writable, right?

Comment: Well, I'd guess that it's accessible from kernel space.. Could be directly mapped into memory somewhere, or accessible on the I2C (OR SM) bus.. If you can find a kernel module that controls it, you can start to trace through the assembly to find where it's writing to.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, you would have to connect to your Mac's SMC chip, as it handles everything battery-related...  Take a look at https://github.com/gcsgithub/smc_util, which will help you read the list of SMC keys (remember to run it with sudo). 
Once you found the key (if you do), use https://github.com/fmorrow/smcwrapper will help you to set the LED state more easily.

Update : My thought about this is, that it is controlled internally by the SMC firmware. Charging=orange, full=Green, that's it. But that's what I thought before I found a way to control the LED that sits in front of your macbook, so.... Never be too sure (especially about Apple) and don't give up ;-)

Comment: Intriguing. Thanks, will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

If it were certain flavors of linux and not OS X then you would simply have a way to access all of the 1-Wire devices via `/sys/bus/w1/devices` - just do a google search for "1-Wire Raspberry Pi Tutorial" and you'll find a bunch of stuff like [Raspberry Pi 1- Wire Digital Thermometer Sensor](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/03/raspberry-pi-1-wire-digital-thermometer-sensor/) which explain how to interface with 1-Wire devices on linux.

However, the next issue you'll face is that there is no `/sys/bus` on Mac OS X - see the question:
[Where is /sys/bus/usb/devices on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/614935/where-is-sys-bus-usb-devices-on-mac-os-x) for more details related to the unfortunate fact that
"OS X doesn't use sysfs"

However, if you do some more digging on similar issues related to accessing `/sys/bus` on Mac OS X or possibly accessing the 1-Wire Bus ( sometimes spelled 1Wire ) it might get you headed in the right direction.

Conceptually it should be very simple to control the 1-Wire Dual Channel
Addressable Switch that is [in the MagSafe power connector](http://www.righto.com/2013/06/teardown-and-exploration-of-magsafe.html) as you mentioned - we just have to find a way to get access to the 1-Wire Bus. I would suggest pursuing that before trying to hack the kernel memory or interface with the SMC controller as mentioned in @`Perceval FARAMAZ`'s answer.

Please post some updates on the question or comments on the answers if you make any more progress.